# When using VBA to open a CSV file directly from internet explorer, I cant then Interact with the file.

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

So I have written some code to download analytic data from twitter by simulating a button click. It's not pretty code but its all I can find to work for now.

I am successfully managing to click the file download, after which a 'frame notification bar' appears with the open, save options. I am successfully clicking open twice, however this is where I run into problems. The problem being that I then want to interact with the data in the CSV file which I have just chosen to open, however the CSV file doesn't come into existence until after the code finishes running. I know there must be a simple solution to this but I just don't know what to search for.

I have tried to play with Wait and DoEvents to see if that helps but no luck so far. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm1.Hide
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")


With appIE
    .Navigate "https://analytics.twitter.com/user/QinetiQ/tweets"
    .Visible = True
End With
Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

Set HTMLDoc = appIE.document
    Set btn = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default ladda-button")(0)
    btn.Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
    Application.SendKeys "%{S}"

Dim o As IUIAutomation
    Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
    Set o = New CUIAutomation
    Dim h As Long
    h = appIE.Hwnd
    h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
    If h = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
    Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Open")
    Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    SendKeys "%(o)"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    DoEvents

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
    Set wb = GetWB
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

End Sub

Function GetWB() As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
 wbName = "tweet"

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like wbName & "*" Then
            Set GetWB = wb
            MsgBox ("Found it")
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wb
    MsgBox ("failed to find worksheet")
End Function
```

I know I have used some really bad techniques and apologies for that. Please can anyone help, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the macro in two by using `Application.OnTime` - this will let you finish the macro (so that the CSV file can open) and then have a new macro scheduled to start a couple of seconds later:

```
    'This is the end of CommandButton1_Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    SendKeys "%(o)"
     Dim wb As Workbook
     DoEvents

    Application.OnTime Now()+TimeSerial(0,0,15), "ContinueDownloadMacro"
    'In 15 seconds the "ContinueDownloadMacro" Sub will start
End Sub

Public Sub ContinueDownloadMacro()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = GetWB
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou very much @Chronocidal! Any chance you can provide an idea as to why this is needed? Is it simply the case that whilst it is in the buttonclick sub CSV files wont open? **Note to others**, this didn't work unless the continuedownloadmacro was in a separate module.

Comment: While the Macro is running, Excel is not accepting "external" instructions (such as from Windows Explorer or Internet Explorer).  You can test this with a very quick macro - `Beep`, wait for 10 seconds, then `Beep` again.  After the first `Beep`, double click on an Excel file to open it up - it won't open until after the second `Beep`.  On the other hand, if your Macro was doing "Save As" instead of "Open" then you could use `Workbooks.Open` to open the CSV file without having to End the Sub first